# 64 bit and 32 bit tools run in one environment

Tags: c++, oracle, build, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

I have a script (bash) which calls 6 tools, 4 of them 32 bit compiled and 2 of them 64 bit compiled. one 32 bit and one 64 bit are oracle dependent tools. As Oracle dependent tools are dependent on dynamic libraries (.so files), I am getting Errors as *.so not found for one of the tool (either 32-bit or 64-bit whichever I set in ORACLE_HOME I guess).
Can anybody please give suggestion, how to manage this situation ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script, before calling 64-bit tools set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to 64-bit *.so.

As per my understanding executable will take the correct *.so, if both 32-bit and 64-bit *.so are there in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH as loaders know to ignore libraries of the wrong architecture.

For more info see this [How do shared libraries work in a mixed 64bit/32bit system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706328/how-do-shared-libraries-work-in-a-mixed-64bit-32bit-system)